# update Enum value in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I wrote a hql query where i want to update an enum value in database,but i don't know how to update an enum value.This is my model

```
@Entity
public class ImageInfo implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "ACTIVE")
private Integer active;

@Column(name = "NOTIFICATION_NUM")
private Integer groupNum;

@Column(name = "PUBLISHED_TIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date publishedTime;

@Column(name = "POSTED_TIME")
private Timestamp postedTime;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PublishIndicator publishIndicator;

}
```

you can see there is an enum field named "publishIndicator" . I want to update this field in a hql query.This is my query

```
session.createQuery("update ImageInfo img set img.active = 1 
and img.publishIndicator = :publish where   img.active = 0  and  
img.publishedTime <:publishedTime ").setParameter("publishedTime", 
date).setParameter("publish", PublishIndicator.PUBLISH).executeUpdate();
```

but i am getting an error

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!"

i know i am doing something wrong with updating enum valur.How can i solve it?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use your (fully qualified) PublishIndicator enum. 
Instead of PublishIndicator.PUBLISH value, so something like this: (assuming your PublishIndicator enum is in com.image package), Use it as com.image.PublishIndicator.PUBLISH

Comment: i tried                                                           
 session.createQuery("update ImageInfo img set img.active = 1 and img.publishIndicator = :publish where   img.active = 0  and  img.publishedTime <:publishedTime ").setParameter("publishedTime", date).setParameter("publish", com.mycompany.stackoverflow.model.PublishIndicator.PUBLISH).executeUpdate();                                                                                                  but still no luck

Comment: Try String.valueOf(PublishIndicator.PUBLISH) to set value in the corresponding param and execute.